# how to implement cost based optimization (join reordering) for join operation in hive?

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

For normal queries `(like count(*) or select *)` below commands works efficiently -

```
set hive.cbo.enable=true;    
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
```

But for **join** operation which runs **without above commands** successfully but with above commands it throws an error -

> Your query has the following error(s):
>
> Invalid OperationHandle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>       getHandleIdentifier()=3583d1d1-373f-4937-846a-e6401a7ff872]

Can anyone give me the answer, Please ?